# R cronjob wrong date and time

Tags: r, date, datetime, cron

I have got a R script that generates a stat for a given time period (1 week). When i run the script from command line everything works as expected. But when i try to generate the stats with a cron job, the date and time functions are not correct.

My crontab:

```
/usr/bin/Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('stats.Rmd', output_file = file.path('/tmp/stats.html'))"
```

The Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Stats"
output: html_document
---

Stats begin: `r as.Date(as.numeric(Sys.Date())-7, origin="1970-01-01")`
Stats end:   `r Sys.Date()`
[...]
```

The Stats begin and end time are always the time of the **last** execution.

I already tried to delete the generated html file and call the Rscript with --vanilla, but I had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself a solution:

Instead of the existing crontab i wrote a little R script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
rmarkdown::render('/.../stats.Rmd', output_file = file.path('/tmp/stats.html'))
```

And updated my crontab

```
.../stats.R
```

This solves the strange behavior in my case.